# how to Customize oracle apex IR pagination

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

how to Customize oracle apex IR pagination like as Classic report Row ranges 1-15 16-30 in select list (set with pagination)

Comment: Pagination is something internal to the apex engine that has hooks in other places - for example you can reset the pagination from a link. I think you have to go with what is available and can't customize.

Answer (score 1):

- run the Interactive report
- go to Actions button
- select **Rows per page**
- choose desired value
- select **Save Report**

  - and select default report settings for all users

Comment: mr. Littlefoot, please at first read carefully my question, i need pagination

Comment: I read what you asked, but - I'm afraid you want something you can't have so I suggested what is available to you. If it doesn't suit your needs, perhaps you'll have to switch to a classic report. Sorry for not being able to help you any better.